# FastAPI: form-data name with a dot

Tags: python, multipartform-data, fastapi, hikvision

I have documentation. Form-data names have dots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This code doesn't work:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/test')
async def test(anpr: UploadFile = File(...), 
               licensePlatePicture: UploadFile = File(...),
               detectionPicture: UploadFile = File(...)
              ):
    ''''''
    return None
```

[image]

**Question: What if we have form-data name with a dot?**

Comment: Hello @Chris. Thank you for your attention to my question. I do not need forms with dots)) This is the documentation for the Hikvision camera.

Comment: define you method like this
`async def test(files: list[UploadFile] = File())`
then loop over your files and pick the one you want by name

Comment: Hello @aramcpp. Thank you for your idea. But this does not work.

Comment: why? you aren't able to get files from camera?

Comment: Debug with Postman: {"detail":[{"loc":["body","files"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add aliases to your file fields like this:

```py
@app.post('/test')
async def test(anpr: UploadFile = File(..., alias='anpr.xml'),
               licensePlatePicture: UploadFile = File(..., alias='licensePlatePicture.jpg'),
               detectionPicture: UploadFile = File(..., alias='detectionPicture.jpg')
              ):
```